# If $f$ is continuous and $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty }\frac{f(x_n)-f(0)}{x_n}=1$, is $f$ differentiable?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

In Calculus class I was discussing the sequential criteria for the limit of a function. Students asked me about this question.  If a limit along every sequence of rational numbers exists then that limit of function doesn't need to exist.

If $f$ is continuous on $(-1,1)$ and $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty }\frac{f(x_n)-f(0)}{x_n}=1$ for every sequence $\{x_n\}$ of rational numbers which converges to $0$, then is $f$ differentiable at $0$?

Comment: It follows from uniform continuity of $f$ on a neighborhood of $0$. It might help to change $f$ in the obvious way to make the alleged derivative $0$ rather than $1$.

Answer (score 5):

By considering $f(x)-f(0)- x$ instead of $f$, we can as well suppose that $g(x_n) = \frac{f(x_n)}{x_n}\to 0$ when $x_n$ is rational and tends to $0$. Let $g(0)=0$ and for $a>0$, let
\begin{equation}
\varepsilon(a) = \sup_{x\in [-a, a]\atop x\in {\mathbb Q}} |g(x)|
\quad{\longrightarrow}\quad 0
\end{equation}
For every $y\in [-a,a]$, one has $|g(y)|\le \varepsilon(a)$ because $y$ can be approached by a sequence of rational points in $[-a, a]$ and $g$ is continuous except perhaps at $0$. It follows that
\begin{equation}
\left|\frac{f(y)}{y}\right|\le \varepsilon(|y|)\to 0
\end{equation}
Hence $f$ is differentiable at 0.